# Vicious net widget and dynamic interface

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome-wm

Ive got pretty standard vicious net widget for the eth0, yet this is my laptop and I move a lot, sometimes I use wlan0, sometimes ppp0. Is there a way in vicious to dynamically choose the active iface?

```
netwidget = widget({ type = "textbox" })
-- Register widget
vicious.register(netwidget, vicious.widgets.net, '<span color="'
.. beautiful.fg_netdn_widget ..'">${eth0 down_kb}</span> <span color="'
.. beautiful.fg_netup_widget ..'">${eth0 up_kb}</span>', 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the ${ carrier} variable to determine which interface is up between eth0, wlan0 or ppp0, then return data of that interface. Do all of this in a format function.

Everything you need is in the README.